# How do you make a has_many association unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

Here's an example:

```
Class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

Now when I create an employee like so:

```
employee = Employee.new(attributes)
```

and then two stores like so:

```
store1 = Store.new(employees: [employee])
store2 = Store.new(employees: [employee])
```

it changes the store_id on the employee to store 2, getting rid of the association with store1. How do I make sure that only one employee can be assigned to one store?

Comment: What do you want to happen here? Do you want an error raised if you try and assign an employee to a store if he's already been assigned to a different one?

Comment: Do you ever want an employee to be able to change stores (like if they transfer)?

Comment: No. In my case if an employee were to change stores, an entirely new record for that employee should be created, and the old one would just change the "current-employee" flag to false. That way the record of them belonging to that store remains (and their termination date)

Answer (score 2):

Try using .build syntax:

So in the create action (I'm assuming this is coming from an employee new action, and that the stores have already been created.) do something like this:

```
#this is the id of whatever store... maybe its a nested resource so it would be something like
#@store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
@store = Store.find(id)
@employee = @store.employees.build(params[:employee])
```

Also be sure you have a belongs_to in your employees model.

Comment: This actually answered my next question, but I also wanted to be safe and make sure that no one else could create these records the way I was doing it. It would have very bad consequences.

Comment: Looks like you need some sort of authorization solution for that. Check out CanCan its simple and extendable.